# gRPC requires http/2

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape some endpoints. When accessing this endpoint through the browser it gave me the response of `gRPC requires http/2` (because the browser send a GET request and it is a POST request).So, when I replicate the request in Postman with the same headers and body of the website, the response status is `200 OK` but the body is empty.
These are some of the headers

```
'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # 'Content-Length': str(len(payload)),
    'Content-Type': 'application/grpc-web+proto',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Grpc-Web': '1',
    'X-User-Agent': 'grpc-web-javascript/0.1',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
```

So, how to replicate the post request on postman to get the same data?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC does require http2, which means you cannot call a gRPC server directly from a browser.

One solution the community has come up with is the [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway), you could take a look at that, in case it will work for you.

Postman does have support for calling gRPC servers, take a look at [this blog post](https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/) for more info.

Comment: Yeah ik that. The browser does send a http/1 request. so that means to get the data we do not have to use http/2 for that endpoint. but I replicate the request on postman it does not work